# How do I use UPDATE and JOIN along with CASES in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

Here the two tables are given,

Account Table:

| Client_ID | AccType | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C100111001 | C | 5000.00 |
| C100111001 | S | 7281.1068 |
| C100111002 | C | 12300.00 |
| C100111003 | C | 1200.00 |
| C100111003 | V | 5000.00 |
| C100112001 | C | 7600.00 |
| C100113002 | C | 1300.00 |
| C100113003 | C | 4500.00 |

Transactions Table:

| Client_ID | AccType | TransType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C100111001 | C | R | 60.00 |
| C100111001 | C | D | 800.00 |
| C100111001 | S | D | 300.00 |
| C100111001 | S | R | 100.00 |
| C100111002 | C | D | 1000.00 |
| C100111002 | C | R | 40.00 |
| C100111002 | C | D | 500.00 |
| C100111002 | C | R | 80.00 |
| C100111003 | C | D | 1000.00 |
| C100111003 | C | R | 100.00 |
| C100111003 | C | D | 100.00 |
| C100111003 | V | R | 100.00 |
| C100111003 | V | D | 70.00 |
| C100111003 | V | D | 30.00 |
| C100113002 | C | D | 1000.00 |

Question is to write a query that updates the balance of all client accounts (Client_ID) of the same Account Type (AccType) in the Account Table from the transactions (Transactions Table) performed on these accounts. In the Transactions Table, we have two types of transactions 'D' and 'R', the TransType 'D' refers to Debit and 'R' refers to Credit.

For example in the first row for both Account and Transactions Table, the Client_ID C100111001 whose Acctype is 'C', the Balance should be updated as 5000+60 as the Amount in Transactions Table is of TransType='R' which means credit. Similarly, for 'D' we will do subtraction in Balance.

I am trying to write an update query by using UPDATE along with JOIN and CASES for 'R' and 'D' but I am unable to do so successfully. Please help

My Query :

```
DECLARE @TransType char
SET @TransType='D'
UPDATE Account 
SET Balance = 
CASE @TransType
     WHEN 'D' THEN Balance - Amount
     ELSE Balance + Amount
END
FROM Transactions
JOIN
Account
ON
Transactions.Client_ID=Account.Client_ID
where Account.AccType=Transactions.AccType
```

My Result Account Table:

| Client_ID | AccType | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C100113003 | C | 4500.00 |
| C100111001 | C | 4940.00 |
| C100111001 | S | 2940.00 |
| C100111002 | C | 11300.00 |
| C100113002 | C | 300.00 |
| C100112001 | C | 7600.00 |
| C100111003 | V | 4900.00 |
| C100111003 | C | 1100.00 |

I have calculated manually that my Result Account Table is not showing the correct Balance, maybe the reason is that I am NOT able to group AccType (C, S, V) properly and therefore it is giving me incorrect balance column values.

Comment: Hint: `CASE TransType WHEN 'C' THEN Balance + Amount WHEN 'D' THEN Balance - Amount END`

Comment: Please enter your desired output

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my query which is giving incorrect values for the Balance column but the kind of output I want is more clear now. Please have a look, thanks in advance

Comment: @Meysam Asadi I have added my Result Table in the end, although it is showing the incorrect values as the calculation is not correct, still you get an idea of how the output table looks like. Thank you

Comment: How C100111001 with AccType S has become 2940.00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is basically right, you just have a bunch of syntax errors.

You don't need the user variable, you just refer to the column in the table.

The `SET` clause goes after `JOIN`, and there's no `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE Account AS a
JOIN Transactions AS t 
ON t.Client_ID=a.Client_ID
    AND a.AccType=t.AccType
SET a.Balance = 
    CASE t.TransType
         WHEN 'D' THEN a.Balance - t.Amount
         ELSE a.Balance + t.Amount
    END
```